# Auto increment in db_schema.xml

Tags: magento2, declarative-schema, db-schema, auto-increment

In [M2 dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html) there is this regarding auto increment:

> identity  Indicates whether a column is auto incremented.

Here's excerpt from my db_schema.xml:

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Entity ID"/>
```

No AUTO_INCREMENT in db is found. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Magento 2.3.4, MySQL 5.7

UPD. It seems like db_schema is cached somewhere. Nothing I do affects it, nor changing padding, nor anything else.

UPD2. Adding a column works. Moreso, even commenting old entity_id column and adding a dummy column with auto_increment works.

Comment: Is this column a primary key or not?

Comment: Yeah, it is a primary key, set by constraint  `<constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>`

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
<table name="custom_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Custom Table">
    <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" padding="10" identity="true" comment="Entity Id"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="entity_id"/>
    </constraint>
</table>
```

Comment: After adding the PRIMARY key it's working.

Comment: yes i know @NagendraKodi

Answer (score 0):

Use `extra="auto_increment"` after `identity="true"` and see what happens.

Comment: Well, nothing happens. I notice that default is set to 0, maybe that's it?

Comment: After adding the PRIMARY key it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Batter understanding you can [view this blog](https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/2023/06/adding-auto-increment-column-in.html).

If you have underestading regarding db_schema.xml then you can add below code or just add this line in your id column **identity="true"**.

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" nullable="false" unsigned="true" identity="true" comment="Entity ID"/>
```